# laravel swagger not working with controller outside of App directory

Tags: php, laravel, swagger

I have a controller `ServiceBookingController` which is outside of laravel traditional `app` directory. I am making swagger documentation. It works fine with the controllers which are inside `App\Http\Controllers` directory. Here is my controller file

```
<?php
namespace Modules\Beauty\Http\Controllers\API;// here is the directory

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ServiceBookingController extends Controller{
/**
     * @OA\Post(
     *     path="/beauty/list-customer-service-bookings",
     *     tags={"beauty_customer_bookings"},
     *     summary="List Customer Bookings.",
     *     operationId="Beauty_Customer_Bookings",
     *     @OA\Parameter(
     *         name="customer_id",
     *         in="query",
     *         description="customer id",
     *         required=true,
     *         @OA\Schema(
     *             type="integer",
     *             default="482"
     *         )
     *     ),
     *     @OA\Response(
     *         response=422,
     *         description="validation errors."
     *     ),
     *     @OA\Response(
     *          response="200",
     *          description="Customer Bookings."
     *     ),
     *     @OA\Response(
     *          response="401",
     *          description="auth failed."
     *     ),
     * )
     */
  public function list_customer_service_bookings(Request $request)
  {
    ...
  }

}
```

I want to use the swagger inside `list_customer_service_bookings` controller for its function `list_customer_service_bookings`. The api request isn't rendering in the swagger ui. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you added this namespace to your `composer.json`? Why are you moving a controller elsewhere?

Comment: @Jerodev I am not. Its already done. Can you please tell me that where to add namespace in `composer.json` file?

Comment: Here is one good article and covered how to generate API documentation with an easy explanation so might be helpful to you. https://www.phparticles.com/laravel/how-to-use-darkaonline-l5-swagger-in-laravel/ Happy Coding 

Answer (score 3):

If you are using darkaonline/l5-swagger, run this command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider "L5Swagger\L5SwaggerServiceProvider"
```

Now, you can open config/l5-swagger.php :
Add your custom directory in annotations. Like this:

```
'annotations' => [
                base_path('app'),   // This is default
                base_path('modules') // Add your directory
            ],
```

I hope it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

To auto load the `Modules` namespace, you need to edit your autoload section of `composer.json` to look like the following:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Modules\\": "modules/"
    }
},
```

Then

run the following commands

```
php artisan clear-compiled
composer dumpautoload
composer update
```

Comment: Hi sir! Thank you for answering. I am now trying this solution.

Comment: I have tried this `"Modules\\": "modules/"` but it is still the same

Comment: The final object is like `"psr-4": {
            "Illuminate\\": "src/Illuminate/",
            "Modules\\": "modules/"
        }`

Comment: `"autoload": {
        "files": [
            "src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php",
            "src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Illuminate\\": "src/Illuminate/",
            "Modules\\": "modules/"
        }
    },`

Comment: I have commented the final `autoload` object. Is everything right?

Comment: please add all of your actual composer.json file to your post